# How can I return a list of values from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

Well I am calling a stored procedure from another stored procedure and I need it to return something like an array.How can I do it?

Comment: well I know they are not implemented but I need to find something

Comment: you could probably use a table instead.. can you elaborate more on what you need to do?

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that you take a look at [Sommarskogs homepage on Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)?

His homepage is full of information, so set aside a few hours to read everything. But start of with this link. It is only about 60 screens full ;-)
IMHO it covers **everything** on passing info between stored procedures. Highly recommended. And you really only need to read the first few pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a temporary table or actual table. Note that (unfortuantely) it doesn't work with table variables.

Set up your table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Foo (Bar NVARCHAR(50), BAZ INT)
```

Then your stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetFoo] AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [BarCol], [BazCol] FROM [BarBazSource]
END
```

Then use the `EXEC` T-SQL command:

```
INSERT #Foo EXEC [GetFoo]
```

Your `#Foo` temporary table now contains the output of the `[GetFoo]` stored procedure.

For more information there's an MSDN article here: ["Getting Creative with EXEC and EXEC()"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175921%28SQL.80%29.aspx)